# Why can't I (and never could) add a bounty to my question?

Tags: support, bounty

I asked this question a while back:

[The afflictions of Tarrare](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/82129/the-afflictions-of-tarrare)

It was fairly well received judging by votes, and think the subject matter is quite intriguing.

However, where I am normally able to bounty questions for which there is no 'canonical' answer, I was not given the option here.

Is there a reason I could never add a bounty to this?

Comment: (note: editing your question does bump it to the top; the question list is cached so you might see an old version. I see your question at the top. Editing old posts by improving them is an acceptable way to bump a question; please do not edit with a sole intent to bump, however).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) from the main meta for more information on bounties.

> You must have at least 75 reputation to start a bounty, and at least as much reputation as the bounty amount.